Проблема с вводом в форму на Python. Selenium, webdriver, chrome
Скрипт должен открывать ссылку на rutube, кликакть на кнопку войти и далее вводить данные в форму. Сайт открывается, кнопка входа нажимается и все виснет на моменте формы
import time
from settings import url
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


options = ChromeOptions()
service = ChromeService(executable_path='/home/haspro/PycharmProjects/views_booster_for_rutube/chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver = Chrome(options=options, service=service)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(20)
button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/section[2]/div[4]/button')
button.click()
time.sleep(20)
driver.refresh()
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body').find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/input').send_keys('HELLO_BLYAT')
time.sleep(20)

В данной коде - неработающая последняя строка. Проблема в ней.
Пробовал и через переменную назначить и в одну строку как сейчас - не помогает
Ошибку выдает следующую:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/input"}
(Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.114); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
